# Trace of gamma particle

Tags: particle-physics, particle-detectors, gamma-rays

Can we have a detector, making traces of gamma particles (gamma photons) visible?

Usually they are invisible until pair born or something.

**UPDATE**

[G-M tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geiger%E2%80%93M%C3%BCller_tube) can detect gamma particles. Can we put many of these tubes in a matrix?

Does [spark chamber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spark_chamber) detect (can detect) gamma particle traces?

Comment: Do you mean *photon*?

Comment: Yes, photon, see my update.

Comment: Rather than stacking many gieger tubes it is conventional to put multiple wires into a single gas volume. This is called a "wire chamber" and they come in many, *many* variations. They were workhorse detectors for decades, though they have fallen a bit out of favor lately. Also drift chambers and time projection chambers. This was fertile ground, but it have been extensively explored.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is no. I myself am not a particle physicist but as far as I know, in contrast to massive particles, photons cannot deposit their energy partially. Either they interact and get destroyed or they do not.

Of course this way, you can make a grid and detect, where photons are coming in, however, as they can not interact multiple times, they will not leave a trace but only a dot. If you make such a detector grid, you just build a camera.

Comment: "_in contrast to massive particles_"- Did you mean "charged" particles instead?

Comment: Photon can give part of it's energy with [Compton effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering).

Comment: @Dims Formally Compton scattering results in a *different* photon. Yes, the distinction there is a little artificial and the same could be said for massive particles, but it is conventional.

Comment: @user5061 No, he didn't. Uncharged massive particles (like neutrons) can do that too.

Comment: @dmckee How exactly does a neutron deposit energy "partially"? As in, leave a trail marking its trajectory?

Comment: They deposit part of their energy by scattering off of protons (in water or hydrocarbons, mostly). Then the protons generate a highly localized signal in the usual way. And assuming a sufficient density of instrumented volume, voila! A slightly ragged and dotted track from your neutron. This is old hat for detectors like TPCs.

Comment: @dmckee By the same reasoning a photon deposits energy continuously after photoelectric effect (?!). Charged particles deposit energy in a continuous way, unlike photons and neutrons that will either interact with the material or not interact at all.

Comment: @user5061 *::shrug::* The conventional way of talking about these processes (at least in the circles that I moved in) makes a verbal distinction between massive particles and photons, but not between neutrons and charged particles until you start talking about PID and energy loss computation. And of course in that case you break things into heavy charged particles; electrons and photons; and neutrons. None of which is to say that there aren't times to make a distinction between neutrals and charged.

Comment: I might add that for sufficiently energetic neutrons the tracks tend to be forward, which is different from the way they behave when they slow down or for that matter in a detector where all the target nuclei are heavy (as in liquid argon or liquid xenon TPCs). In those case they tend to scatter in highly random direction even at fairly high energy.

Comment: @dmckee I agree that under some conditions a neutron will have a high chance of interacting with matter and produce a trail of its would-be trajectory, but this is not addressing the quote: "_massive particles... can deposit their energy partially [while photons] either interact or do not_". This quote implies that neutrons would not behave as photons, that is, either interact, or not. Therefore, in my opinion the quote might have to be rephrased.

Comment: @user5061 the dots in your quote are fairly important! While it is true, that also neutrons either interact or don't but after an interaction, a neutron is still around to interact again, while a photon is destroyed, having deposited all its energy.

Comment: Actually this pointed out yet another problem; Rayleigh scattering. Unlike Compton scattering mentioned earlier (which can arguably be considered as "destruction" of the initial photon), in Rayleigh scattering i find it hard to describe the scattered photon as "different". Anyway, i believe that the answer can occasionally lead to wrong assumptions, but then again, it might be just me.